# v2.6.1, Structure, Multiple Relationships - How do I render the page URL?

Tags: structure, relationships

I am using v2.6.1 and the new multi-relationships feature.  I am also using Structure.  My question is, how do I get the structure URL inside of the new relationships tag.  So lets say my related entries field name is "related_news", how could I populate the hyperlink URL?:

```
{related_news}
    <a href="{related_news:page_url}">{related_news:title}</a>
{/related_news}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used that new feature, but it would be the same as the Pages module since we store our data in the same place.